# Python: Sub does not substitute pattern for replacement

Tags: python, replace

I have been going this bit of code for what seems to be a lifetime and cannot seem to get it to work.

```
translation = re.sub("'''[a-zA-Z0-9].*?'''", "<b>[what do I put here to copy [a-zA-Z0-9].*?</b>", translation)

Here I'm trying to replace " ''' [text] ''' " with " <b> [text] </b>. What would I have to put between <b> and </b> to make it copy across the text?
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a capturing group and refer to it by `\1`:

```
translation = re.sub(r"'''([a-zA-Z0-9].*?)'''", r"<b>\1</b>", translation)
```

Comment: Hi Janne, thank you for your answer. I have attempted to create a group but when I print the new string, the markup shows a small box between <b> and </b>.

Comment: pattern = "'''([a-zA-Z0-9].*?)'''"
    pattern_obj = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE)
    translation = pattern_obj.sub("<b>\1</b>", translation)

Comment: @user2421580 It is important to use a raw string `r"<b>\1</b>"` (the r in front makes a raw string). Otherwise `\1` is a control character. Or double the backslash: `\\1`

Answer (score 0):

```
translation = re.sub("'''([a-zA-Z0-9]*)'''", r"<b>\1</b>", translation)
```

Something like that?